# create sliding view in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, slide

I need to create a sliding view in titanium so it creates an effect like this:
[image]

I have tried this:

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

            if (x == 0) {
                x = x1 = e.x;
            }
            x1 = e.x;
            if (x > (x1 + deviceWidth * 0.25)) {

                viewImage.animate({
                    left : 0,
                    x : 0,
                    x1 : 0,
                    duration : 1,
                    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
                });
                viewLabel.animate({
                    left : 0,
                    duration : 1,
                    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
                });

            } else if (x < (x1 - deviceWidth * 0.25)) {
                viewImage.animate({
                    left : (deviceWidth * 0.15) * (-1),
                    duration : 100,
                    x : 0,
                    x1 : 0,
                    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
                });

                viewLabel.animate({
                    left : (deviceWidth * 0.15) * (-1),
                    duration : 100,
                    curve : Ti.UI.ANIMATION_CURVE_LINEAR
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is that in the same screen the images ar inside a scrollView and each image has an click event

```
viewImage.addEventListener('click', function() {

});
```

I would like to create something that moves only the pixels that the user has moved with the finger so it seams mor normal and not with animation.

Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqw8Tp2wvVs) in min 0:58, and that works for android and IOS simultaneous

Comment: Have you tried to put a horizontal scroll view into your vertical scrollview? I have used this to build something similar.

Comment: thanks Robin Ellermann it work perfectly (vielen dank, es hat mein problem gelöst)